# Emulating vi directional keys using AutoHotKey

Tags: vim, autohotkey

Currently I am using following code for changing keyboard layout:

```
// vim.ahk
CapsLock::Send, {CTRLDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}{SHIFTUP}{CTRLUP}{CTRLUP}
    return
!^CapsLock::CapsLock

CapsLock & j  :: Send {Down}
CapsLock & k  :: Send {Up}
CapsLock & h  :: Send {Left}
CapsLock & l  :: Send {right}
CapsLock & p  :: Send {PGUP}
CapsLock & `; :: Send {PGDN}
CapsLock & ^  :: Send {home}
CapsLock & $  :: Send {end}
```

Is this code stable enough? The problem is that sometimes `CapsLock` undesirably turns on

**Update:** I found out that `CapsLock` turns on when it is pressed with any key except above keys. (`hkll;pae`)

Comment: I use something extremely similar.  What type of answer are you looking for? Have you run into issues when using this code?

Comment: I just want know is it in its optimal form or it can become better?

Comment: Note that `j` in Vim is down and `k` is up.

Comment: 1. When does `Capslock` turn on? 2. What is you `Capslock::` mapping for used for?

Comment: @WilliamBettridge-Radford Question has been updated, I did not get your second question.

Comment: What is `CapsLock::Send, {CTRLDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}{SHIFTUP}{CTRLUP}{CTRLUP}` for? What do you want to happen when you press CapsLock?

Comment: @WilliamBettridge-Radford Currently I use CapsLock to switch between keyboard layouts.

Comment: Problem with this is that if you try Ctrl+Shift+Capslock+h it should select the word, just like ctrl+shift+leftArrow does. I haven't been able to fix that myself. Also Ctrl+Capslock+h should jump a word left.

Comment: Yes, I also have this problem. You can not select any text using `hjkl`. But yet the code is very useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to the top of your script.

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff

!^CapsLock::CapsLock
```

It should stop all Capslock events that you don't create.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm

Comment: It was desirable that CapsLock could be turned on by using `ctrl+shif+CapsLock`, but I think keeping it always off is better than accidentally turning on. Thanks.

Comment: That should still work.

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: It's working for me here. Can you try it with just those two lines in their own file? Maybe try `+Capslock:Capslock` as well.

Comment: This does not work: `SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff !^CapsLock::CapsLock` But this works: `SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff +Capslock::Capslock`

Comment: It's works for me. Is the hotkey matching at all? 1. `!^Capslock::tooltip, hello` 2. Check Autohotkey's Key History.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped messing around with the *CapsLock as a modifier* because of consistency reasoning (*you're going to be so lost without it on another person's pc*). So, instead of `CapsLock` I use `ALT+SHIFT (!+)` modifiers because it's not common but still comfortable enough for easy reach. **I was able to replicate arrowkeys `up/down/left/right (kjhl)` w/ AutoHotkey like how Vim does it but couldn't navigate those keys when using Windows ALT+TAB (see below for how I accidentally found a solution).**

Then, I accidentally came across a solution to use Vim-navigationkeys while on Windows ALT+TAB without it disappearing. I'm not able to explain it but it just works and i'll post my current setup and show you the difference with my accidental finding.

## AHK VIM-NAVIGATION HOTKEY

> If these keys don't fit you comfortably, pls. change it to your liking. I just prefer to have `shortnavigation-keys (up/down/left/right)` matching vim and had put customization only for the `longnavigation-keys (home/end/pgup/pgdn)`

`!+[::SendInput, {Escape}
!+k::SendInput, {Up}
!+j::SendInput, {Down}
!+h::SendInput, {Left}
!+l::SendInput, {Right}
!+p::SendInput, {Home}
!+u::SendInput, {End}
!+o::SendInput, {PgUp}
!+i::SendInput, {PgDn}
!+0::SendInput, ^{Tab}  ; tabmove-forward
!+9::SendInput, !^{Tab}  ; idk why, but doesn't tabmove-backward`

## WIN ALT+TAB w/ VIM-NAVIGATIONKEYS (*static menu, due to another prior hotkey press*)

- activate `!+9::SendInput, !^{Tab}`

  - Once after pressing ALT+SHIFT+9, continue holding ALT+SHIFT and navigation using kjhl :D

## WIN ALT+TAB w/ VIM-NAVIGATIONKEYS (*can't, because menu closes*)

- `ALT+TAB`

  - Now continue holding Alt and then hold Shift aswell and now begin using the mimicked vim navigation keys *which is kjhl*, notice the window disappears :(

NOTE

- Common keys are typical keys used for basic function like cut/copy/paste and tab switching all of which use only a combination of one modifier & a single key press unless it's for Windows Virtual Desktop navigation

  - e.g. Windows Virtual Desktop switching uses CTRL+WIN+LEFT/RIGHT
  - it's a good idea to still use normal hotkeys and not customize over it too much unless you can prove why your way is better
- What is the difference between short and long navigation-keys?

  - shortnavigation-keys: up/down/left/right
  - longnavgiation-keys: home/end/pgup/pgdn